# jquery html 5 dragstart .on('dragstart',function(e){}) e.dataTransfer.setData() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag

chrome throw err:  Cannot call method 'setData' of undefined,
I find the e is not  equal to window.event(it havn't propert dataTransfer);both has very  big different

I find both almost equal in the click event.

I used http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js.

I don't use drag feature,I just want know why.
it is new feature in html 5,jquery still behind of it ?.
or jquery team don't want support it?? or some other reason

Comment: Can you please provide an example of the code your using?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

In the callback function you get a jQuery wrapper over a native event. Use the `originalEvent` property of passed argument:

```
$('...').on('dragstart', function (event) {
    event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('...', '...');
});
```

P.S. dont' forget to set the `draggable="true"` attribute for the element to be dragged.

Comment: thank you very much.
why jQuery doesn't just callback native event

Comment: @zsytssk It is done to provide cross-browser predictable contents and behaviour. Read this http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

Comment: would `event.dataTransfer.setData()` work then if jQuery is not included on the page

Comment: @rizwaniqbal, yes it would, since it is a method on a native event obejct. Although, you'll have to add the 'dragstart' event listener to the element by using either 'addEventListener' method or 'ondragstart' property for it. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DragDrop/Recommended_Drag_Types.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery creates it's own event object, and it doesn't have a dataTransfer property yet. This adds dataTransfer to the event object.

> $.event.props.push('dataTransfer');