# Cannot read property 'setData' of undefined - jQuery UI Touch Punch

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, typescript, jquery-ui-touch-punch

I am unsure why `setData` and `getData` is undefined whenever I call it through jQuery UI.

I am doing

```
$(`#selector`).draggable({
            start: function(event: any) {
                drag(event);
            },
            stop: function(event: any) {
                console.log('stopped');
            }
        });
```

and in drag():

```
drag(event: any) {
    event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData("text, application/x-moz-node", event.target.id);
}
```

The `originalEvent` is in reference to this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25671377/how-to-setdata-getdata-when-using-jquerys-triggerdragstart-for-html5s-d)

However, I am still receiving the same results.

`Cannot read property 'setData' of undefined`

I am using typescript as well (not sure how much of a difference this makes).

Answer (score 3):

it’s an issue with jQuery and you can resolve it by adding the following code when the page loads or before using dataTransfer

```
jQuery.event.props.push('dataTransfer');
```

Example:

```
jQuery.event.props.push('dataTransfer');
 event.dataTransfer.setData("Text", event.target.id);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the jQuery wrapper.We have to add 'dataTransfer' to Event object.

> **Note**: `$.event.props` was removed in jQuery 3.0 so you will need to
>   use `$.event.addProp` instead.

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.event.addProp('dataTransfer');

});
```